# How can I use indexof and substring to find words in a string?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the constructor :

```
var tempFR = File.ReadAllText(file);
GetResults(tempFR);
```

Then :

```
private List<string> GetResults(string file)
            {
                List<string> results = new List<string>();

                string word = textBox1.Text;
                string[] words = word.Split(new string[] { ",," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
                {
                    int start = file.IndexOf(words[i], 0);
                    results.Add(file.Substring(start));
                }

                return results;
            }
```

words contains in this case 3 words System , public , test
I want to find all the words in file and add them to the list results using indexof and substring.

The way it is now start value is -1 all the time.

To clear some things.
This is a screenshot of the textBox1 :
That is why I'm using two commas to split and get the words.

[image: textBox1]

This screenshot showing the words after split them from the textBox1 :

[image: Getting the words is fine with two commas]

And this is the file string content :

[image: file content]

I want to add to the List results all the words in the file.
When looking at the last screenshot there should be 11 results.
Three time the word using three times the word system five times the word public.

but the variable start is -1

Update :

Tried Barns solution/s but for me it's not working good.
First the code that make a search and then loop over the files and reporting to backgroundworker :

```
int numberofdirs = 0;
        void DirSearch(string rootDirectory, string filesExtension, string[] textToSearch, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> filePathList = new List<string>();
            int numberoffiles = 0;
            try
            {
                filePathList = SearchAccessibleFilesNoDistinct(rootDirectory, null, worker, e).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

            }
            label21.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        label21.Text = "Phase 2: Searching in files";
                    });
            MyProgress myp = new MyProgress();
            myp.Report4 = filePathList.Count.ToString();
            foreach (string file in filePathList)
            {
                try
                {
                    var tempFR = File.ReadAllText(file);

                    _busy.WaitOne();
                    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    bool reportedFile = false;

                    for (int i = 0; i < textToSearch.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (tempFR.IndexOf(textToSearch[i], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                        {
                            if (!reportedFile)
                            {
                                numberoffiles++;

                                myp.Report1 = file;
                                myp.Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString();
                                myp.Report3 = textToSearch[i];
                                myp.Report5 = FindWordsWithtRegex(tempFR, textToSearch);
                                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, myp);
                                reportedFile = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    numberofdirs++;
                    label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        label1.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}", numberofdirs, myp.Report4);
                        label1.Visible = true;
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

I have the words array already in textToSearch and the file content in tempFR then I'm using the first solution of Barns :

```
private List<string> FindWordsWithtRegex(string filecontent, string[] words)
        {
            var res = new List<string>();

            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                Regex reg = new Regex(word);
                var c = reg.Matches(filecontent);
                int k = 0;
                foreach (var g in c)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());
                    res.Add(g + ":" + k++);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Results of FindWordsWithtRegex");
            res.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
            Console.WriteLine();

            return res;
        }
```

But the results I'm getting in the List res is not the same output in Barns solution/s this is the results I'm getting the List res for the first file :

In this case two words system and using but it found only the using 3 times but there is also system 3 times in the file content. and the output format is not the same as in the Barns solutions :

[image: Output is wrong]

Comment: You should only have 1 comma in your split parameter. You want to split the string any time there's a single comma, not when a double comma is encountered.

Comment: @itsme86 The words is fine I'm getting all the words. The reason I'm doing double commas ,, is because that is how it is in the textBox1.Text when I'm doing a search for multiple words I'm using ,, to separate them in the textBox1 that's why I'm using two commas. words is fine I'm getting the 3 words in the textBox1.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi the text file should contain normal sentences with spaces between words. You're saying your textbox1 has **System,,public,,test** without spaces? Is that correct? Because if it is this code would work and the words.Length would be 2 not -1

Comment: Is this some kind of homework assignment? Why force the use of `IndexOf`? Why create a `List` of words instead of  a `List` of the number of times each word in "words" was found? Seems like a result of `{"using:3", "System:3", "public:5"}` would make more sense, based on the information given.

Comment: Sounds you need two `foreach` loops. One for each line and another for each word since you want to search the same line again and again for each word. Try `var tempFR = File.ReadAllLines(file);` instead and the two `foreach` suggestion. Better to use a stream reader  to search line by line instead of loading everything in memory. Btw, What does the output look like? Just curious to know.

Comment: @Barns If not indexof then what to use for this and how ?

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a result as I indicated above? `{"using:3", "System:3", "public:5"}`?

Comment: @Barns Yes I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative using `Regex` instead of using `IndexOf`. Note I have created my own string to parse, so my results will be a bit different.

EDIT

```
    private List<string> FindWordsWithCountRegex(string filecontent, string[] words)
    {
        var res = new List<string>();

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex(word, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var c = reg.Matches(filecontent).Count();
            res.Add(word + ":" + c);
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your first solution but the output format and the results are wrong. I edited my question with what I did and how I used your solution in my code.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi :: I will need a little time to look through your edited code. Thanks for trying.

Comment: OK. I've had a look at your code. Could you verify that the `string[]` "words" contains all the strings you expected ("using", "System") and that in particular "System" is capitalized and NOT "system"?

Comment: Yes, words contains system and using first system then using and system is not capitalized (maybe it's better to make it for both lower case and upper case?) but I confirm for what you asked.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi :: I have change the code to just the variation where the `List` is generated for the results `{"using:5", "System:5"...` and I made it ignore case.

Answer (score 1):

Simple change this part and use a single char typically a space not a comma:

```
string[] words = word.Split(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int start = file.IndexOf(words[i],0);
```

start will be `-1` if the word is not found.
[MSDN: IndexOf(String, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_Int32_)

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    int start = file.IndexOf(words[i], 0);
    // only add to results if word is found (index >= 0)
    if (start >= 0) results.Add(file.Substring(start));
}
```

If you want all appearance of the words you need an extra loop

```
int fileLength = file.Length;
for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    int startIdx = 0;
    while (startIdx < fileLength ){
        int idx = file.IndexOf(words[i], startIdx]);
        if (start >= 0) {
            // add to results
            results.Add(file.Substring(start));
            // and let Word-search continue from last found Word Position Ending
            startIdx = (start + words.Length);
        }

    }
    int start = file.IndexOf(words[i], 0);
    // only add to results if word is found (index >= 0)
    if (start >= 0) results.Add(file.Substring(start));
}
```

MayBe you want a caseinsensitiv search
`file.IndexOf(words[i], 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);`  [MSDN: StringComparer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=netcore-3.1#properties)